# How to user $in query in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I want to fetch records when permission = User.

Below is my colletions:

```
"_id":ObjectId("59177f050c9db20629f4562"),
"profile":
{
    "permissionGroups" : [
      "Admin",
      "Restaurant",
      "Salesperson",
      "User"
    ]
}
```

Fetch only in permission is User.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: refer this documentation https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/in/

Answer (score 2):

Well first, access the permissionGroups array inside profile obj and then run a query simply matching the string like this. You don't need to run a $in unless you have multiple strings in array to match with:

```
db.getCollection('collection name').find({"profile.permissionGroups" : "User"})
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `$in` is what you're looking for. `$in` queries an array against a field, so let's say you search `permissionsGroup: {$in: ['User', 'Admin']}`, and that would return all records that could find either `User` or `Admin`.

In this case you can simply search for `permissionsGroups: 'User'`. Mongo is smart enough to recognize `permissionGroups` as an array, and test the given value against the fields in that array.